# server1 instance in websphere shuts down regularly

Tags: web-services, websphere

i have a WSDL web service in the server1 instance of websphere.

this server1 instance shuts down regularly. **there are no error logs being generated every time the shutdown occurs.**

however, whenever the server1 instance of websphere is **started**, these errors and exceptions are generated:

1. The certificate (Owner: "CN=SOAPRequester, OU=TRL, O=IBM, ST=Kanagawa, C=JP") with alias "soaprequester" from keystore "D:\IBM\WEBSPH~1\APPSER~1\etc\ws-security\samples\dsig-sender.ks" has expired: java.security.cert.CertificateExpiredException: NotAfter: Sat Oct 01 19:24:06 CST 2011
2. The certificate (Owner: "CN=SOAPProvider, OU=TRL, O=IBM, ST=Kanagawa, C=JP") with alias "soapprovider" from keystore "D:\IBM\WEBSPH~1\APPSER~1\etc\ws-security\samples\dsig-receiver.ks" has expired: java.security.cert.CertificateExpiredException: NotAfter: Sat Oct 01 19:30:39 CST 2011
3. Method createManagedConnctionWithMCWrapper caught an exception during creation of the ManagedConnection for resource jms/BPECF, throwing ResourceAllocationException.  Original exception: javax.resource.spi.ResourceAdapterInternalException: createQueueConnection failed
4. com.ibm.mqservices.MQInternalException: MQJE001: An MQException occurred: Completion Code 2, Reason 2063
   MQJE027: Queue manager security exit rejected connection with error code 23
5. javax.jms.JMSSecurityException: MQJMS2013: invalid security authentication supplied for MQQueueManager

my questions are:
1. is MQ required by the WSDL service?
2. are any of these 5 errors possible for causing the frequent downtimes?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand you have `WebSphere Process Server` configured with `WebSphere MQ` as message bus.

`MQ Queue` might be represented as JMS binding in `SOAP over JMS` configuration. [IBM article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/ws-soapmqjms/).

Regarding errors:
First 2 errors are simple - certificates have expired. You should update it.

I assume 3 -5 exception are 1 error - there is answer to this question [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448492/mqjms2013-invalid-security-authentication)

2063 is security related problems.

Comment: does this mean that WebSphere MQ is required for the web service to run?

Comment: Check web service binding. You can read more in doc: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/sr/v7r5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.sr.doc%2Fcwsr_mq_integration_overview.html